# How to display a modal dialog if users click a link?

Tags: shiny, modal-dialog

I'd like to display a modal dialog if users click a link. Currently, the modal dialog works if users click on the action button.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

```
## app.R ##

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$act_guide, {
    showModal(modalDialog(

      h5("Data Guidelines"),

      tags$ol(
      tags$li("Must have Resp_ID as the first column, occasion_ID as second and dependent variable as the third"), 
      tags$li("Must have no missing value in any fields")
      ), easyClose = TRUE, footer = NULL)
      )
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  h4("Data guidelines"),
  br(),
  actionButton("act_guide", "Click Here!")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `actionLink` instead of `actionButton` to trigger the pop-up as shown below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

if(interactive()){
  shinyApp(
    ui <- fluidPage(
      h4("Data guidelines"),
      br(),
      actionLink(inputId = "link1", label = "Click Here!")
    ),

    server = function(input, output, session){

      observeEvent(input$link1, {
        showModal(modalDialog(
          h5("Data Guidelines"),
          tags$ol(
            tags$li("Must have Resp_ID as the first column, occasion_ID as second and dependent variable as the third"), 
            tags$li("Must have no missing value in any fields")
          ), easyClose = TRUE, footer = NULL)
        )
      })

    }
  )
}
```

An alternate way is to use `bsModal` inside ui.R to trigger the pop-up as shown below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

if(interactive()){
  shinyApp(
    ui <- fluidPage(
      h4("Data guidelines"),
      br(),
      actionLink(inputId = "link1", label = "Click Here!"),

      bsModal(id = "modal1", title = "Test Modal", trigger = "link1",
              h5("Data Guidelines"),
              tags$ol(
                tags$li("Must have Resp_ID as the first column, occasion_ID as second and dependent variable as the third"),
                tags$li("Must have no missing value in any fields")
              ), easyClose = TRUE, footer = NULL)
    ),

    server = function(input, output, session){

    }
  )
}
```